# Counting Records Based on Unique Date

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a frame with a column of dates (some dates with multiple records) and a numeric column. I want a frame that lists one date per record, the sum of the numbers for each date, and the number of occurrences of records for each date.

Starting frame:

```
SomeDate    SomeNum
10/1/2013   2
10/1/2013   3
10/2/2013   5
10/3/2013   4
10/3/2013   1
10/3/2013   1
```

I can get the sum of SomeNum per unique date with the following:

```
newDF<-unique(within(df, {
    SumOfSomeNums <- ave(SomeNum, SomeDate, FUN = sum) 
}))
```

But I can't figure out how to get a count of the number of times each unique SomeDate occurs.

I want:

```
SomeDate   SumOfSomeNums  CountOfSomeDate
10/1/2013   5             2
10/2/2013   5             1
10/3/2013   6             3
```

What would get me the CountOfSomeDate data?
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuing with your approach, use `length` as your aggregation function:

```
unique(within(mydf, {
  SumOfSomeNums <- ave(SomeNum, SomeDate, FUN = sum)
  CountOfSomeDate <- ave(SomeDate, SomeDate, FUN = length)
  rm(SomeNum)
}))
#    SomeDate CountOfSomeDate SumOfSomeNums
# 1 10/1/2013               2             5
# 3 10/2/2013               1             5
# 4 10/3/2013               3             6
```

---

However, there are many alternative ways to get here.

Here's an `aggregate` approach:

```
do.call(data.frame, aggregate(SomeNum ~ SomeDate, mydf, function(x) c(sum(x), length(x))))
#    SomeDate SomeNum.1 SomeNum.2
# 1 10/1/2013         5         2
# 2 10/2/2013         5         1
# 3 10/3/2013         6         3
```

And a `data.table` approach:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(mydf)

DT[, list(Count = length(SomeNum), Sum = sum(SomeNum)), by = SomeDate]
#     SomeDate Count Sum
# 1: 10/1/2013     2   5
# 2: 10/2/2013     1   5
# 3: 10/3/2013     3   6
```

Comment: **Thank you!** That works great! I'll play with the other options as well. I'm going to be adding additional columns in the future so maybe those options will better serve my needs as I proceed.

Comment: @BigKage, no problem. I think you'll find the `data.table` syntax pretty easy to pick up, and it's great on large datasets.